# How to catch custom exceptions in the REST controller that are thrown inside @CommandHandler functions

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, axon

I've built a simple Spring Boot REST API using Kotlin and the Axon Framework, patterned off of the ["Food Ordering App" example on YouTube](https://youtu.be/7oy4w5THFEU?list=PL4O1nDpoa5KQkkApGXjKi3rzUW3II5pjm&t=599), and now I'm trying to return a 400 response from my POST `/api/user/register` endpoint when a client tries to create a new account with a username that's already in use.

So, just like Steven did in the above video, I created a new custom exception class `UsernameTakenException`, and I throw this exception from inside my create user @CommandHandler function if the username is already in use. I then expected that I would be able to `catch (e: UsernameTakenException) { ... }` this new exception from within my endpoint's controller method, and return the 400 response containing the exception's message.

But after doing some tests, it seems like my endpoint function can only ever catch exceptions of type `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`, and not the custom `UsernameTakenException` type that I created.

Here is my `UserManagementController.kt` file:

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/user")
class UserManagementController(
    val commandGateway: CommandGateway,
    val queryGateway: QueryGateway
) {
    @PostMapping("register")
    fun createUser(@RequestBody createUserReqBody: CreateUserRequest): ResponseEntity<Map<String, Any>> {
        return try {
            val result: CompletableFuture<Any> = commandGateway.send(
                CreateUserCommand(
                    createUserReqBody.username,
                    createUserReqBody.password
                )
            )
            ResponseEntity.ok(
                mapOf(
                    "userId" to result.get()
                )
            )
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) { // I want to catch `UsernameTakenException` instead
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(
                mapOf(
                    // This at least gets the message string to the client:
                    "error" to "${e.cause?.message}"
                )
            )
        }
    }

    // other endpoints...
}
```

Here's my `User.kt` aggregate file:

```kotlin
@Aggregate
data class User(
    @AggregateIdentifier
    var userId: UUID? = null,
    var username: String? = null,
    var password: String? = null,
    var userService: UserService? = null
) {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null, null)

    @CommandHandler
    constructor(command: CreateUserCommand, userService: UserService) : this(
        UUID.randomUUID(),
        command.username,
        command.password
    ) {
        if (userService.usernameExists(command.username)) {
            // This message needs to get back to the client somehow:
            throw UsernameTakenException("This username is already taken")
        }
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(
            UserCreatedEvent(
                userId!!,
                command.username,
                command.password
            )
        )
    }

    // other handlers...
}
```

And here's my `exceptions.kt` file:

```kotlin
class UsernameTakenException(message: String) : Exception(message)

// other custom exceptions...
```

Am I missing something here, or going about this the wrong way?

Comment: for what reason are you using CompletableFuture? If this is a synchronous operation you do not need it. 
If you stilll need to use it, then you have to research on how to get original exception when using CompletableFuture...its quite easy to find information about that...

Comment: Indeed, either use the sendAndWait on the command gateway, or properly handle the future, fo example using Reactor like in the [giftcard demo](https://github.com/AxonIQ/giftcard-demo/blob/455944adbab3f1efbcd79983c8c39f77176d1bf6/src/main/java/io/axoniq/demo/giftcard/rest/GiftCardController.java#L58).

Comment: @Carlos Because I'm just following Axon's tutorials, and they use CompletableFuture: [example 1](https://github.com/AxonIQ/food-ordering-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/io/axoniq/foodordering/gui/FoodOrderingController.java#L33), [example 2](https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/blob/master/distributed-exceptions/src/main/java/io/axoniq/distributedexceptions/rest/GiftCardController.java#L41).

Comment: @GerardKlijs I'm not understanding how switching from `send` to `sendAndWait` will solve my problem of how to catch a custom exception?

Comment: @eriegz moving to `sendAndAwait` will wait for the result, which makes the exception pup up. compared to `send` which the exception will get lost, if there is never a call made to `get()` on the future.

Comment: @GerardKlijs Ah, thanks for explaining. In my code above I am indeed performing a `result.get()` just before returning the success response, and so that's what triggers the `catch (e: ExecutionException)` below it. My problem is just that I want to catch my custom exception class, and not some generic wrapper exception.

Comment: I see, it probably works if the `UsernameTakenException` would extend either from `AxonException` or `RuntimeException` currently it's a checked exception.

Comment: @GerardKlijs I finally figured it out after digging through AxonIQ discussion boards. See answer below. The solution is that you have to extend `CommandExecutionException`, and then pass your custom exception fields as a `details` sub-object.

Comment: My apologies for the format in the video referred to, @eriegz. Since we produced those videos, some changes around exception wrapping inside the Framework have been introduced. Specifically for distributed scenarios when we cannot ascertain whether the (command) dispatching end is aware of the returned exceptional result. I am glad to see you've found a resolution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

So first of all, I *was* on the right track with my original code, and ultimately I was able to make it work with just a few tweaks which I'll share below.

Problem explanation: for reasons that I don't totally understand, the Axon Framework intentionally ***does not*** propagate any custom exceptions up the stack, and instead wraps / converts them to `CommandExecutionException` type, and allows developers to put their error codes, error categories, error messages, etc. inside a special `details` field. The idea is that this way you'll never run into a situation where the command handler application (because this is a distributed application) has the custom exception class on their path but the client *doesn't*. More details [in the docs](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/messaging-concepts/exception-handling) and in [this AxonIQ forum post](https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/checked-exceptions-on-a-custom-command-gateway/2510/3).

> Aside: In my opinion the docs could've been *way* more clear on this, and could've maybe included a code example to drive the point home. I can see I'm not the first person to be confused by this behaviour. Also, if the whole reason for not propagating a custom exception is that the client would *also* need that exception class in their path, then... couldn't the client just add it to their path? Forcing the client to access all of the information it needs from a `details` sub-field of `CommandExecutionException` solves nothing — there is still tight coupling between the client and the command handler when it has to get its error codes from `e.getDetails().myErrorCode`. So how is it any different than just adding the custom exception class to both paths in a distributed application?

Anyways, here's my solution for throwing custom exceptions inside of command handlers and having them trigger different HTTP responses:

`UserManagementController.kt`:

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/user")
class UserManagementController(
    val commandGateway: CommandGateway,
    val queryGateway: QueryGateway
) {
    @PostMapping("register")
    fun createUser(
        @RequestBody createUserReqBody: CreateUserRequest
    ): CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>> {
        return commandGateway.send<UUID>(
            CreateUserCommand(
                createUserReqBody.username,
                createUserReqBody.password
            )
        ).thenApply { ResponseEntity.ok(mapOf("userId" to it.toString())) }
    }

    // other endpoints...
}
```

`User.kt`:

```kotlin
@Aggregate
data class User(
    @AggregateIdentifier
    var userId: UUID? = null,
    var username: String? = null,
    var password: String? = null,
) {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null)

    @CommandHandler
    constructor(
        command: CreateUserCommand,
        userService: UserService
    ) : this(
        UUID.randomUUID(),
        command.username,
        command.password
    ) {
        if (userService.usernameAlreadyTaken(command.username)) {
            throw UsernameAlreadyTakenException()
        }
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(
            UserCreatedEvent(
                userId!!,
                command.username,
                command.password
            )
        )
    }

    // other handlers...
}
```

`exceptions.kt`:

```kotlin
data class RestExceptionDetails(
    val message: String,
    val httpCode: HttpStatus
)

// So as you can see, your custom exception essentially becomes a POJO:
class UsernameAlreadyTakenException() : CommandExecutionException(
    null,
    null,
    RestExceptionDetails("This username is already taken", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
)
```

`RestExceptionHandling.kt`:

```kotlin
@RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = [UserManagementController::class])
class RestExceptionHandling {
    @ExceptionHandler(CommandExecutionException::class)
    fun handleRestExceptions(
        e: CommandExecutionException
    ): ResponseEntity<Map<String, Any>> {
        val details: RestExceptionDetails? = e.getDetails<RestExceptionDetails>()
            .orElse(null)
        if (details == null) {
            throw e
        }
        // The values you pass inside the `details` field can now change which
        // HTTP responses get sent back to the client (e.g.: 400, 404, etc.)
        return ResponseEntity.status(details.httpCode).body(
            mapOf("error" to details.message)
        )
    }
}
```